# ArrayList == null in if statement

Tags: java

I do not have a way of really testing this without completely the other code I am working on but I just wanted to confirm this. If I am trying to code this statement:

```
If a node contains only positives, set decision to true. 
If it contains only negatives set it to false
```

where pos is an ArrayList of all of the positive examples of a node and neg is othe same but with all of the negatives. Would this statement be valid?

```
 if(!node.pos.isEmpty() && node.neg.isEmpty())
     node.decision = true;
 if(!node.neg.isEmpty() && node.pos.isEmpty())
     node.decision = false;
```

So pretty much I am wondering if i put that the ArrayList is != null then does that mean that it must contain at least 1 thing and then when I put == null then that means it is empty?

Comment: No. Being null is not the same as being empty.

Comment: No null does not mean empty. Use the built in `isEmpty()` method

Comment: @GBlodgett okay so like how i edited it to be now?

Comment: You possibly need to check for both `null` & `isEmpty` in that order - depending on how those lists are initialised

Answer (score 1):

No. An `ArrayList` is an object and will only be `null` if it hasn't been instantiated using the `new` keyword.

Use [`ArrayList.isEmpty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#isEmpty()) or [`ArrayList.size() > 0`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#size()).

Comment: Don't use `ArrayList.size() > 0.` for checking if a collection is empty. You should use the `isEmpty()` method.

Comment: @DroidX86 agreed, but figured it made sense to make him/her aware that the method exists.